# Exclusion constraint that allows overlapping at the boundaries

Tags: postgresql, overlap, exclusion-constraint

I tried to have a PostgreSQL constraint so that there will be no overlap between two date intervals. My requirement is that the date `c_from` for one entry can be the same as `c_until` for another date.

Eg: "01/12/2019 12/12/2019"  and "12/12/2019 31/21/2019" are still date ranges that do not conflict. I have "[]" in my query but it seems not to work.

```
user_no   INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES usr,
c_from      DATE DEFAULT NOW(),
c_until     DATE DEFAULT 'INFINITY',
CONSTRAINT unique_user_per_daterange EXCLUDE USING gist (user_no WITH =, daterange(c_from, c_until, '[]') WITH && )
```

When I have the date range above, I get this error:

```
(psycopg2.IntegrityError) conflicting key value violates exclusion constraint "unique_user_per_daterange"
```

Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ranges that do *not* include one of the ends:

```
daterange(c_from, c_until, '[)')
```

Then they won't conflict, even if one interval ends at the same point where another begins.

Comment: Thank you  very much for the solution, and also for fixing the question description